# How to mock exhange.getIn().getBody(HttpServletRespose.class) with mockito

Tags: java, spring, junit, apache-camel, mockito

I am trying to write the junit for file in camel.

Below servletResponse which I want to mock.

Processor:

```
HttpServletResponse servletResponse = exchange.getIn().getBody(HttpServletResponse.class);

ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = servletResponse.getOutputStream();

IOUtils.copy(inputStream, servletOutputStream);

servletOutputStream.flush(); 
servletOutputStream.close();
```

I have tried to write junit for this.

To mock the servletResponse here is below code:

```
HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);

ServletOutputStream outputStream = mock(ServletOutputStream.class);

when(response.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(outputStream);
```

But am getting null for servletResponse which is in the processor.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `when(...)` for `exchange.getIn()` and `message.getBody(HttpServletResponse.class)`. I would suggest yo to use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and `@Mock` annotations. Have a look at the test:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyExchangeServiceTest {
    private MyExchangeService testedObject = new MyExchangeService();

    @Mock
    private Exchange exchange;
    @Mock
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    @Mock
    private Message message;
    @Mock
    private ServletOutputStream outputStream;

    @Test
    public void servletResponseIsRead() throws Exception {
        when(exchange.getIn()).thenReturn(message);
        when(message.getBody(HttpServletResponse.class)).thenReturn(response);
        when(response.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(outputStream);

        testedObject.process(exchange);
    }
}
```

Update, here is my service:

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class MyExchangeService {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        HttpServletResponse servletResponse = exchange.getIn().getBody(HttpServletResponse.class);

        servletResponse.setStatus(200);

        servletResponse.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

        servletResponse.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename='xyz.csv'");

        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = servletResponse.getOutputStream();

        System.out.println(" servletOutputStream: " + servletOutputStream.getClass());
    }
}
```

Test output:

```
 servletOutputStream: class org.mockito.codegen.ServletOutputStream$MockitoMock$501469028
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.I have tried the above solution but still servletResponse is coming as null. I think if we are creating a mock of exchange which is creating a new instance of exchange that's why HttpservletResponse.class is not the instant of exchange.getIn() which has been used in processor.

Comment: I have added `MyExchangeService` could you add it to your project and run the test from the answer on it?

Comment: As you can see from `Test output ` `servletResponse` and `servletOutputStream` is not null.

Comment: Thanks but still it's null for me. In test class able to see the HttpServletResponse for mock but when it comes to processor it's null.

Answer (score 1):

The **best solution is not to use** `exchange.getIn().getBody` and therefore **having no obligation to mock it**.

The [Processor interface](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/processor.html) is a bit clumsy to use and hard to test. Therefore you can use **simple beans that are easy to use and test**.

Instead of writing a Processor that calls `exchange.getIn().getBody` you can write a **Java bean that gets injected the message body** for free. See the [Camel Docs for more Annotations to inject message parts into Beans](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/parameter-binding-annotations.html).

This method in a POJO does the same as your processor.

```
public void processServletResponse(@Body HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {
    servletResponse.setStatus(200);
    ...
}
```

You can call the POJO in the route with

```
.bean(MyBean.class)
```

Testing this bean is very easy thanks to [Inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). You don't need to get your ServletResponse, it is given to you.

Answer (score 0):

Late in the game, but
I was facing similar issue.
Something like below fixed my issue.

```
when(exchange.getIn()).thenReturn(message);
when(exchange.getIn().getBody(HttpServletResponse.class)).thenReturn(response);
```